# Two statements about partial limits and intervals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and $I=(a,b)$ an open interval such that every $L\in(a,b)$ is a partial limit of $(a_n)$. Decide whether or not the following statements are true:

1. $\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $(a,b)$.
2. If $(a_n)$ is bounded and $\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n, \limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n \right )\subseteq (a,b)$ then $\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}\subseteq(a,b)$

**My attempt**:

1. I believe it is true. Proof: Suppose the statement is false, That is, there exists $x,y\in I, x<y$ such that for all $n$, $a_n \leq x$ or $a_n \geq y$. Because $\frac{x+y}{2} \in I$, it is a partial limit of $(a_n)$ and thus there are infinite number of values of $n$ such that $|a_n-\frac{x+y}{2}|<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. In particular, there exists $a_N$ such that $$\left |a_N-\frac{x+y}{2} \right|<\frac{y-x}{2}$$ or $$x<a_N<y$$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $a_n \leq x$ or $a_n \geq y$ for all $n$. Thus $\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is indeed dense in $(a,b)$.

What do you think of the proof?

2. I believe it is false but I can't come up with a counterexample. Any suggestions?

Comment: How could 2. be true? You could replace $a_1,a_2$ with anything and not change  $\liminf$ or $\limsup.$

Comment: @zhw - I agree. What do you think of 1?